# Adding an event handler to a web.config gives error: configuration file is not well-formed XML

Tags: templates, events, web-config, sitecore, sitecore8

Per [this blog post](http://www.symsoftsolutions.com/Blog/List/Relocate-Links-from-Sitecore-Branch), I am trying to add an event to my Sitecore web.config file, and do exactly what he is doing. This is exactly how I have it in my file.

```
<events timingLevel="custom">
      ...
      <event name="item:added">
        <handler type="BenefitVault.Core.Helpers.SitecoreEvents, BenefitVault" method="OnItemAdded" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Data.Fields.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </event>
      ...
</events>
```

However, when I try to hit my local site, I get the error below. It looks like a syntax error, but I'm not seeing the problem. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've added this entry into directly into web.config then you do not need the patch declaration, just add it without, e.g:

```
<events timingLevel="custom">
      ...
      <event name="item:added">
        <handler type="BenefitVault.Core.Helpers.SitecoreEvents, BenefitVault" method="OnItemAdded" />
      </event>
      ...
</events>
```

But you should avoid making changes to the  section of config directly, it will hinder you when trying to upgrade and mean you have to try to figure out what changes have been made. Instead you should use a [patch include file](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/60/include_file_patching_facilities_sc6orlater-a4.pdf), which is what the original article you linked to is referring to (and the reason it is failing when you modify directly)

Create a new config file under `/App_Config/Include` folder, (optionally create it under `/App_Config/Include/zProjectName` to really [ensure it gets patched in last](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/12/22/reorganisation-of-include-config-patch-files-in-sitecore-8/))

**/App_Config/Include/zMyProject/EventHandlers.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events timingLevel="custom">
      <event name="item:added">
        <handler type="BenefitVault.Core.Helpers.SitecoreEvents, BenefitVault" method="OnItemAdded" 
                 patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Data.Fields.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @jammykam. It looks like we already have a file in a similar (but not exactly the same location, at /App_Config/Include/zBVDeveloper.config. This file also already has a <sitecore> section. Can I just insert everything in my new <events> handler inside there? When I do this, I get the following error, which I'm having trouble figuring out: http://imgur.com/ZDTcw71

Comment: @iaacp Yes, you can add it to that file. The error you are facing is because it cannot find the related code. Make sure you have typed the Namespace/Class name correctly and the library file name is correct, in this instance it is expecting a dll named BenefitVault to be output. Also make sure you have deployed your code to IIS

Comment: Is it possible I don't want to use Sitecore.Kernel in that patch:after section, or anything else is wrong in the patch part? I've triple checked the dll name (which I actually had wrong originally) and the name space. I currently have the namespace BenefitVault.Core.Helpers, with the class named SitecoreEvents inside of it. The class has a method named OnItemAdded, and both the class and method are public.

Comment: You don't have to use the `patch:after` part, all it tells Sitecore is where to patch your event:handler in the order that the events fire. If you leave that part out then your processor will be added in last. So you could just have `<handler type="BenefitVault.Core.Helpers.SitecoreEvents, BenefitVault" method="OnItemAdded" />` (or similar)